# Matlab midiToolBox readmidi error

Tags: matlab

I want to import the midi file into Matlab. It's sure that the midiToolBox is installed. I do as following:

```
>> fn = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mathmatica\Higher.mid'
>> >> nmat = readmidi(fn)
```

And the error message:

```
Undefined function 'midi2text' for input arguments of type 'char'.
Error in readmidi (line 38)
    midi2text(fn, 'MF2T.OUT'); % uusin mex konvertteri [2. tammikuuta 2003]
```

Extra infomation:

- [code for readmidi.m](https://code.google.com/p/mamlib/source/browse/readmidi.m). The code online is old, the error line is 59

  ```
  midi2text(fn, 'MF2T.OUT'); % uusin mex konvertteri [2. tammikuuta 2003]
  ```
- And the *midi2text* maybe the name of the midi2text.dll in the toolBox Package.

Answer (score 0):

`midi2text` is a MEX function that is not present in the repo that you have linked to.  That's why you are getting that error. However, upon simple searching, I found this link:

http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/~sdubnov/CATbox/miditoolbox/

This contains the `midi2text` function as both a Windows DLL and MEX wrapper for Mac OS and Unix.  However, these were compiled using a 32-bit compiler, so if you are using a 64-bit operating system, this function will not work.

Upon reading the header of `readmidi.m`, the last supported version of MATLAB that this function was supported on was version 5.3, which was released on [January of 1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history).  With all of this combined, you probably have zero chance in running this on your current configuration and you should probably look for something else.

---

Doing a simple Google search for reading MIDI files in MATLAB found this more current link:

http://www.kenschutte.com/midi

I suggest you try the above instead of relying on a very old piece of code.